# Why are the terms filled when they are actually empty?

Tags: 8, commerce

Below is the JSON output of a product I am having the issue with:

```
  {
     "StkGrupKodu1" : "10090",
     "StokAdi" : "7 Parça Kombine Anahtar Takımı",
     "StkGrupKodu2" : "",
     "SiparisVerilebilir" : true,
     "StokMiktari" : 0,
     "StkGrupKodu4" : "",
     "StokTipiAdi" : "Ticari Mallar",
     "KDVOrani" : 18,
     "StokTipi" : "00000",
     "DovizCinsi" : "EUR",
     "Fiyat" : "34.00000",
     "StkGrupKodu3" : "",
     "StkGrupKodu5" : "",
     "PasifStok" : false,
     "EskiBilgileri" : {
        "EskiStokKodu" : "",
        "DegistirmeTarihi" : "1920-04-23T00:00:00"
     },
     "StokKodu" : "JBM50563"
  },
```

In this e-commerce system, I am consuming a web service and creating corresponding products. With a few products such as the above and a few others, I am having this dreadful issue. As you can see, StkGrupKodu2 and StkGrupKodu3 are empty but when I go to the edit page of the product, it's not empty. You can see from the screenshot below:

[image: terms issue]

This is the code I am using to associate terms with products

```
foreach ($excel_products as $e) {
    $req = \Drupal::httpClient()->get("http://mitapp.mitacan.com/b2b/api/vStkLib/GetStkKodlist?UserCode=B2BUSER&StokKodu=".$e->stokkodu);
    $res = $req->getBody();
    $res = json_decode($res);
    $data = $res->Data[0];
    $sid = \Drupal::database()->select("commerce_store_field_data", "csfd")->fields("csfd", ["store_id"])->condition("default_currency", ($data->DovizCinsi == "TRL")?"TRY":$data->DovizCinsi)->execute()->fetchCol();
    $product = Product::create(["type" => "default"]);
    <snip>
    if (!empty($data->StkGrupKodu1)) {
        $tid_1 = \Drupal::database()->select("taxonomy_term__field_stok_grup_kodu", "ttfsgk")->fields("ttfsgk", ["entity_id"])->condition("field_stok_grup_kodu_value", $data->StkGrupKodu1)->execute()->fetchCol();
        $tid_1 = (!empty($tid_1[0]))?$tid_1[0]:"";
    }
    if (!empty($data->StkGrupKodu2)) {
        $tid_2 = \Drupal::database()->select("taxonomy_term__field_stok_grup_kodu", "ttfsgk")->fields("ttfsgk", ["entity_id"])->condition("field_stok_grup_kodu_value", $data->StkGrupKodu2)->execute()->fetchCol();
        $tid_2 = (!empty($tid_2[0]))?$tid_2[0]:"";
    }
    if (!empty($data->StkGrupKodu3)) {
        $tid_3 = \Drupal::database()->select("taxonomy_term__field_stok_grup_kodu", "ttfsgk")->fields("ttfsgk", ["entity_id"])->condition("field_stok_grup_kodu_value", $data->StkGrupKodu3)->execute()->fetchCol();
        $tid_3 = (!empty($tid_3[0]))?$tid_3[0]:"";
    }
    $tids = [$tid_1, $tid_2, $tid_3];
    $tids = array_filter($tids);
    <snip>
    foreach ($tids as $tid) {
        $product->field_stok_grup_adi[] = [
            "target_id" => $tid,
        ];
    }
  <snip>
}
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be a PHP issue and not drupal. You're not clearing your $tid_1,$tid_2,$tid_3 values within your for loop

So when $data->StkGrupKodu1 isn't set for example the value of $tid_1 is still that of the last time $data->StkGrupKodu1 did exist.

You could declare your $tid_1,$tid_2,$tid_3 variables at the top of your foreach loop so they get set similar to what you're doing if the database results null

Comment: Shouldn't `$tid_1 = (!empty($tid_1[0]))?$tid_1[0]:"";` be doing exactly that?

Comment: But that would only happen if $data->StkGrupKodu1 exists. Think through the steps and what would $tid_1 be if that $data->StkGrupKodu1 didn't exist which would mean you'd never get into that if statement for that loop

Comment: Gotcha. Trying that now. Thank you :)